# Pyramid routing to class methods

Tags: pyramid

From the [pyramid documentation](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/_modules/pyramid/config/views.html), there exists an `attr` argument on configurator's `add_view` that states:

> The `attr` value allows you to vary the method attribute used
>             to obtain the response.  For example, if your view was a
>             class, and the class has a method named `index` and you
>             wanted to use this method instead of the class' `__call__`
>             method to return the response, you'd say `attr="index"` in the
>             view configuration for the view.

With this in mind, I'd like to route all requests under `/myrequest` to the class `MyRequest`. Given the following class:

```
@view_defaults(renderer='json')
class MyHandler(object):
    def __init__(self, request):
        self.request = request

    def start(self):
        return {'success': True}

    def end(self):
        return {'success': True}
```

It would seem the way to do this would be in the configuration, add these lines:

```
config.add_view(MyHandler, '/myrequest', attr='start')
config.add_view(MyHandler, '/myrequest', attr='end')
```

and so on, for all the methods I want routed under MyHandler. Unfortunately this doesn't work. The correct way to do this appears to be:

```
config.add_route('myroutestart', '/myroute/start')
config.add_route('myrouteend', '/myroute/end')
config.add_view(MyHandler, attr='start', route_name='myroutestart')
config.add_view(MyHandler, attr='end', route_name='myrouteend')
```

This seems like an awful lot of boilerplate. Is there a way to bring this down to 1 line per route? Or more ideally, 1 line per *class*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example #4 in the [Route and View Examples](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_cookbook/en/latest/pylons/examples.html) from The Pyramid Community Cookbook v0.2, Pyramid for Pylons Users, offers the following.

```
# Pyramid
config.add_route("help", "/help/{action}")

@view_config(route_name="help", match_param="action=help", ...)
def help(self):   # In some arbitrary class.
    ...
```

Although this cookbook recipe mentions pyramid_handlers as one option to do this, the article ["Outgrowing Pyramid Handlers"](https://michael.merickel.org/2011/8/23/outgrowing-pyramid-handlers/) by one of the maintainers of Pyramid encourages the use of Pyramid's configuration.